How can I get Orkes Conductor subwofkflow tasks when we call main workflow without calling each subworkflow?
I have a main workflow and a subworkflow containing multiple human tasks. I want to retrieve details of all the human tasks across both the main workflow and subworkflow with a single API call. So far, it seems that we need to first fetch the main workflow, which provides details of the subworkflow. Then, for each subworkflow ID, we need to make separate calls to Orkes. Is there a simpler way to obtain all task details in one request?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.
